# FullCalendar truncate text in title issue

Tags: fullcalendar, truncate

I have this weird issue in FullCalendar 3.3.1 with Bootstrap 3 where I have a function that truncates long title text, it works fine but it affects the behaviour of the calendar, see below:

My code:

```
// Truncate long title texts
    function truncate(str, max) {
      return str.length > max ? str.substr(0, max-1) + '…' : str;
    }
    // Get current time
    var d = new Date();
    var curtime = d.getHours()+":00:00";        
    // Calendar properties
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        aspectRatio: 1.35,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
        },
        scrollTime :  curtime,
        defaultView: "agendaWeek",
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end) {
            if(start.isBefore(moment())) {
            alert('The date/time you selected is in the past!');
            } else {
                $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
                $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
                $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
                // Initialize the DateRangePicker for event add modal
                $('input[name="endDate"]').daterangepicker({
                    singleDatePicker: true,
                    showDropdowns: true,
                    locale: { format: "YYYY-MM-DD" },
                    startDate: "<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+2 days')); ?>",
                    minDate: "<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+2 days')); ?>",
                    parentEl: "#endDate"
                });
            }
        },
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            var cur30min = d.getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000);
            if (usrStat == 1 && event.start > cur30min) {
                element.bind('click', function() {
                    $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
                    $('#ModalEdit #title').val(event.title);
                    $('#ModalEdit #room').val(event.room);
                    $('#ModalEdit #cat_id').val(event.cat_id);
                    $('#ModalEdit #tel').html(event.tel);
                    $('#ModalEdit #uname').html(event.uname);
                    $('#ModalEdit #eadd').html(event.eadd);                     
                    $('#ModalEdit').modal('show');
                    // Initialize the DateRangePicker for event edit modal
                    $('input[name="endDateEdit"]').daterangepicker({
                        singleDatePicker: true,
                        showDropdowns: true,
                        locale: { format: "YYYY-MM-DD" },
                        startDate: moment(event.dowend).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                        minDate: "<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+2 days')); ?>",
                        parentEl: "#endDate"
                    });
                });
            }
            var title = truncate(event.title,20);
            element.find('.fc-title').html(title);
        },
        eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) { 
            edit(event);
        },
        eventResize: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc) { 
            edit(event);
        },
        events: [
        <?php 
        foreach($events as $event):             
            $start = $event['start'];
            $end = $event['end'];
            $color = "#aeaeae";
            $editable = "true"
            // Define the event information
            $event_dtls = "{";
            $event_dtls .= "id: '".$event['id']."',";
            $event_dtls .= "title: '".$event['title']."',";
            $event_dtls .= "start: '".$start."',";
            $event_dtls .= "end: '".$end."',";
            $event_dtls .= "room: '".$event['room']."',";
            $event_dtls .= "cat_id: '".$event['cat_id']."',";
            $event_dtls .= "tel: '".$event['tel']."',";
            $event_dtls .= "uname: '".$event['name']."',";
            $event_dtls .= "eadd: '".$event['eadd']."',";
            $event_dtls .= "color: '".$color."',";
            $event_dtls .= "approved: '".$event['approved']."',";
            $event_dtls .= "category: '".$event['category']."',";
            $event_dtls .= "editable: ".$editable;
            $event_dtls .= "},";
            echo $event_dtls; 
        endforeach; 
        ?>
        ]
    });
```

So it does the job of truncating long text in calendar view, however if I add an event, when I click on a cell the cell don't highlight anymore like the image here:
[cell_highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYVIC.jpg)

Adding an event still works but it doesn't highlight the cell anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to be able to help.  First: `If I add an event` - how are you adding events?  Next: clicking on cells does not highlight them by default, so you must have some `eventClick` and/or `dayClick` code to do that, right? Show us that.

Comment: I create events by clicking a cell, it will get highlighted like I showed on the pic on my post and it opens up a modal form. I believe this is a default behavior of FullCalendar, isn't it?

Comment: No, it is not.  Fullcalendar does not highlight anything when you click, it does not create events by clicking a cell, and it does not open modals. That behaviour must come from your own code.  If your highlighting is not working, you need to show us the code that does the highlighting.

Comment: Yes you are right. I borrowed this code from here -- https://github.com/jamelbaz/FullCalendar-BS3-PHP-MySQL. Also using Bootstrap 3. I have now updated my code above, hope this is ok.

Answer (score 0):

For my purposes, I wanted to truncate the event title so it doesn't overflow into other cells.

```js
  const truncateString = (s="", num) => {
    if (s.length <= num) {
      return s;
    }
    return s.slice(0, num) + "...";
  };

const cleanedBgEvents = rawBgEvents.map((e) => ({
      start: new Date(e?.start?.dateTime),
      end: new Date(e?.end?.dateTime),
      title:
        truncateString(e.subject, 12) || truncateString(e.summary, 12),
      display: "background",
    }));

// Pass these events to <FullCalendar events={cleanedBgEvents} /> Component
```